# How to make a good atmospheric entry?

Tags: rodina

I've tried multiple times to enter a planet's atmosphere but abandonned because it is way to long and I feel that i am not moving at all.

How can I enter a planet's atmospehere in a fast and without blowing up my ship with all the flames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of this source, I figured it out: http://rasmase.com/rodina/index.php?title=Reentry

I'd recommend you do what the game recommends. Start by lowering the atmosphere setting to 0.5 for practice. Increase by 0.1-0.2 as you feel better about it.

Start in cruising speed (3rd gear, from space) and align your ship just below the horizon. The speed/gear and the horizon thing is important. Try to maintain just below the horizon. It's hard and this is where the practice comes in. You can lose control and start to burn up; if this start to happen you can regain control (at least at atmosphere=0.5). While you're entering the atmosphere the ship will appear on fire and that is ok as long as you don't have the warning. That is the atmosphere going around your ship from what I could discern. That said, I don't know if this is avoidable but my ship wasn't taking damage as long as it was controlled so I considered it fine.

Depending, it takes 30-60 (long) seconds to get through. Nice music will play once you are through though! Just focus on maintaining the control of the angle; try to focus on your target.